# Why is this object black in my scene?

Tags: materials, lighting, scene

No matter how much light is pointed at the projector screen behind the chair, the object comes out black in the render. It has the same material as everything else. Also why does the door look the way it does with those dark shadows?

[Blender File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gKM20wmF-HvpOno-ZYQ9xmTZ5a0_ggly/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

FYI to the moderators, I tried using blend exchange and it wouldn't work.

Comment: Is it missing a texture, or output shader node set to the wrong renderer?

Comment: It has a texture and the output is "all" so it should work in both cycles and evee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay this took me a bit to figure out. The problem was on the `screen_roller` object hidden in the viewport, not the `Plane.002` object that's overlapping it.
You were right the material is fine! It's identical to the materials used on other objects, and even removing it doesn't change anything. The problem is the [normals](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.82/modeling/meshes/properties/object_data.html?highlight=normals#normals) for the screen are facing the wrong way, so the light doesn't reflect off the surface toward the camera. I fixed this by clearing the [custom split normals](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.83/modeling/meshes/structure.html#modeling-meshes-normals-custom) data:
[image: Object Data Properties > Geometry > Clear Custom Split Normals Data]
This data was taking priority over anything calculated directly from the geometry. Though if you need the custom normals, you're free to adjust them manually.

[Edit] Oops didn't see you ask about the door! But it looks like it's having the same problem as the screen, just to a lesser extent. Clearing or tweaking the split normals should fix it as well.

Comment: Hi there : ). Nice and detailed answer . I like it. Next time don't forget to ass some links on certain words like normals which direct u to the blender manual page.

Comment: You are a god! That fixed all my problems and has created tremendous relief in my project. Thank you!!

Comment: @Nxdhin2005 thanks for the feedback. i added some links and tried to improve the clarity a bit

Comment: @NickAbbott haha i'm glad i could help! those models were looking good. happy blending :)

Comment: Perfect !! Thanks for editing your question. :D

Answer (score 0):

Check the face orientation of the object. If it is red, go to edit mode, select all, <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>
See if that makes a difference.

(Face orientation is in the overlays tab)

Comment: Hi there : ) .Please use the answer section to post detailed and simplified answer. Do not post something that you are not sure about. To ask such things use the comment section. . If it is the normals explain what normals are and give a brief intoduction on it.Thank u